# Detect AngularJS promise resolved but empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I make a service call it returns a promise. The success function fills in the data eventually. But if there was no data, how do I detect this?

```
GuideControllers.controller('SettingsCtrl',[ '$scope', "Settings",
    function ($scope, Settings) {
        // gets data to fill in the modal sidebar
        // when the modal "submit" is hit, the underlying page is redisplayed
        var bp = 0;
        $scope.settings = Settings.get({ namespace: 'api', resource: 'settings', userId: 'current'}, function(data){
            $scope.genreFilters = data.genreFilters;
            $scope.releaseDateFilter = data.releaseDateFilter;
            $scope.ratingRangeFilter = data.ratingRangeFilter;
            $scope.sortBy = data.sortBy;
            for( var i = 0; i < $scope.sortBy.length; i++ ){
                if($scope.sortBy[i].selected === "selected"){
                    $scope.selectedOrder = $scope.sortBy[i];
                }
            }
        })
    }
]);
```

When the data is returned all fields are undefined because of an empty response. This is not an error, I just want to check before referencing undefined data. Data is not a collection so I can't check it's size. Data itself is not undefined since it's a promise and is marked as resolved.

I could catch the referencing undefined exception, but that's not really a good use of exceptions IMO.

My current work around is to check if some fields in data are undefined.

Comment: Well, like you said, this is not an error so there is not much to check and your workaround seems like a good solution. I don't know if that's a possibility but maybe you could better structure the api responses generated by the server so this is simpler/cleaner to detect. Check out http://jsonapi.org/ for some tips.

Comment: What does `Setting.get` do? Does it simply return the promise created by $http or what? It is hard to tell what is going on without knowing that.

Comment: @user284764: I could add a flag in the data that is set when it's otherwise empty--true, but maybe checking for undefined is not so bad. @ Edwin: ```Settings.get``` returns either data to fill in a form, with the current user's settings for highlighting, or it returns empty if there is no authenticated user since they will not be allowed to fire the UI to show settings. The form is created any time the page is loaded and can simply be invisible and blank.

Comment: Where exactly are you using a promise in your example. Your question is about promises, but your code snippet has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: The promise is $scope.settings but when the promise is resolved with the callback variable 'data'. True, I don't resolve $scope.settings but the question is about 'data' being empty. Checking to see if some attribute of 'data' is undefined seems to be the only way to tell that 'data' is empty? If I actually resolved the promise by storing 'data' in $scope.settings, would that make a difference? I can certainly do that if it helps.